# Why do I get "Page not found" with my code?

Tags: 8, routes

I just created a new module but I can't manage to access it.

Here is the home.info.yml

```
name: Home
description: Ownzones Homepage
type: module
core: 8.x
```

Here is home.routing.yml

```
home.oztest:
  path: '/oztest'
  defaults:
    _content: '\Drupal\home\Controller\HomeController::oztest'
    _title: 'Ownzones'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

And here is the HomeController:

```
namespace Drupal\home\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

class HomeController extends ControllerBase {
  public function oztest() {
    $element = array(
      '#markup' => 'Hello, world',
    );

    return $element;
  }
}
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong, and when I try to access /oztest I get a message saying *The requested page could not be found*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

_content is no longer used, wherever you found that is outdated. Use _controller instead.

Comment: Thank you! So I should read every line of the changelog every time they update Drupal, right?

Comment: There are a lot of outdated D8 tutorials and documentation out there, because things changed a lot in the last year, after there was a believe that we're almost done and people wrote those tutorials and documentation. It will improve now, there aren't that many changes anymore since beta version started.

Comment: I tried above given code by replacing _content by _controller. Still getting page not found. Have any idea?

Comment: I'm also still getting page not found